# PDE integral of parts

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations

**Question**

> \begin{align} u_t &= -a(x)u_{xx} \\ u(0,t) &= u(1,t) = 0 \end{align}
>
> where $u = u(x,t), \ t > 0, \ x \in [0, 1]$ and $a(x)$ is positively
>   defined between (0,1). Given
>
> $$E(t) = \int_{0}^{1} u^{2}(x,t)dx$$
>
> show that $E'(t) \le 2E(t)$.

**Attempt at solution:**

\begin{align}
E'(t) &= 2 \int_{0}^{1} uu_t dx\\
&= -2 \int_{0}^{1} u \cdot a u_{xx} dx \\
&= -2 \left[a uu_x \bigg|_{0}^{1} - \int_{0}^{1} a u_x^2 dx \right] \\
&= 2 \int_{0}^{1} a u_{x}^2 dx \\
&\geq 0
\end{align}

I'm not sure how to move forward or if the integral is correct?

Answer (score 1):

You know that $a(x)$ is positive and $(u_x)^2$ must be nonnegative, which means the integral must be positive and you've shown your desired result of $E'(t) \leq 0$.

Comment: Yes of course

Sorry, I read the question wrong, but I changed it to the correct one now

Comment: Sorry to ask, but are you sure it is typed correctly now? 

Also, $a(x)$ is a function of $x$ so I think the integrand obtained using integration by parts is incorrect.

Comment: Yeah:)! I'm really unsure about how to do the integral because it's 3 products so it's most likely not correct

Comment: I'm not sure what to do then. Integration by parts would have to assume that $a$ is differentiable almost everywhere so that we can use product rule in the integrand to get
\begin{align*}
-2\int_0^1 (au)u_{xx} \ dx &= -2\left[ auu_x\bigg|_0^1 - \int_0^1 (a'uu_x + a(u_x)^2) \ dx \right]\\
\end{align*}
but I'm not sure where to go from here.